# ActionScript 3 Button CLICK event not firing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, mouseevent, event-listener

So right now after tirelessly working with my restart button in my flash game the button still will not register the click.

Here is the code for the button:
Why I think the problem is with the MouseEvent.CLICK because the trace() flag doesn't show up.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    /**
      * ...
      * @author Andrew Xia
      */
    public class RestartButton extends SimpleButton
    {
        public function RestartButton(setX:Number, setY:Number)
        {
            this.x = setX;
            this.y = setY;
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        public function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
                        trace("HELLO!");
            dispatchEvent( new NavigationEvent( NavigationEvent.RESTART ));
        }
    }
 }
```

And here is the code for the screen that I added the button to:

```
  package 
  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Andrew Xia
     */
    public class GameOverScreen extends MovieClip 
    {
        public var restartButton:RestartButton;
        public var scoreLabel:TextField;
        public var scoreBox:TextField;

        public function GameOverScreen()
        {
            Mouse.show();
            restartButton = new RestartButton(0, 108);
            addChild(restartButton);

            var textFormat = new TextFormat();
            textFormat.size = 54;

            scoreLabel = new TextField();
            scoreLabel.x = -185;
            scoreLabel.y = -36.75;
            scoreLabel.height = 73.5;
            scoreLabel.width = 185;
            scoreLabel.text = "SCORE: ";
            scoreLabel.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            scoreLabel.setTextFormat(textFormat);
            addChild(scoreLabel);

            scoreBox = new TextField();
            scoreBox.x = 0;
            scoreBox.y = -36.75;
            scoreBox.height = 73.5;
            scoreBox.width = 143;
            scoreBox.text = (String)(Main.playerScore);
            scoreBox.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            scoreBox.setTextFormat(textFormat);
            addChild(scoreBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, this problem has been driving me crazy and I'm sure its probably just a really stupid error on my part but I would appreciate it immensely if you guys can help me out.

Comment: First, do other traces work? If no, you are compiling in "release" mode where traces are just not compiled. And second, you might add funky code into the listener and just test if these work. Say `parent.graphics.moveTo(0,0); parent.graphics.lineTo(500,500);` so that game over sprite will get a line drawn across it. If it works, you have to dispatch navigation event not to `this` but to some other class, up to `stage`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you add any DisplayObject for any of the button states. If there is nothing to click - the click will never happen.

Try this as your RestartButton class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;

    public class RestartButton extends SimpleButton
    {
        public function RestartButton(setX:Number, setY:Number)
        {
           super(GRAPHICS_FOR_UP, OVER, DOWN, HIT); // the object can repeat

           this.x = setX;
           this.y = setY;
           addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        public function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
                    trace("HELLO!");
            dispatchEvent( new NavigationEvent( NavigationEvent.RESTART ));
        }
    }
}
```

if for some reason you don't want to add the graphics, just add the hit area with

```
super(null, null, null, HIT_GRAPHICS);
```

Now you can click the button.

Comment: It's likely that this class is GUI designed, thus graphics for hit,up,over,down are pre-placed. But yes, hit area is the thing to look at.

Comment: I didn't run into this problem myself, but I thought that if he generated custom class for this object and super() is not defined a blank super is generated compile time and the actual reference to the SimpleButton objects are null, but they are ok for the DisplayObject... It's hard to know the real problem, just guessing :) It's not technically even a programming question, just troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however vesper is right in that I've designed the button through the GUI already and I don't believe it's the hit area because the button goes through the animations.

Comment: Creative Magic thank you I will take a look at that and yes you are right this is more trouble shooting but I really have been working on this for a while and I just want to get this bug over and done with :P Anyways thank you all so far for you help!

Comment: @AndrewX I tried to just paste your code and it worked fine. I think it's either something on top is covering your button, or you're in release mode where trace() messages are removed by the compiler upon compile.

Comment: That does present an interesting situation. I'll have to look into it.   Thanks @CreativeMagic!